# Is it possible to use a component based approach with Play?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

i am about to start implementing my first project with Play. **It's basically a rendering Engine, which is connected to a CMS Backend/Service.** It retrieves a page object from the CMS Backend (as Json). This page object will contain components. The Play App has to iterate over these components and invoke a corresponding controller for each component and include its results in the final page. **Each of this component should be represented by a separate controller in the new Play application.** In a framework like Spring MVC, i could use the `jsp:include` tag to include the result of a controller into a page. Is there something similar with Play? I have not found anything yet.

Thx!

**PS:**

- I know that all templates are functions, that you can call from other templates. But this way, i would have to make sure, i have the right parameters available. But i want basically to forward the request to a controller and include its result in my page.

Comment: You could call the controller methods directly, rather than redirecting to them. This should be effectively the same as redirecting, but without the overhead of additional HTTP requests (even if it they are just local). Are you using Java or Scala? It seems like you are using Java. If so, and your controller methods are static, simply do  `comp1 = Component1Controller.getComp1(...); comp2 = Component2Controller.getComp2(...); ...` The only parameters you need to pass are the same ones you'd need to pass in your GET/POST request anyways.

Comment: I am coming from Java, but i will use Scala. Sure i can get a reference to the needed controllers and call their respective Actions to obtain their result. But i how do i work with those results? How can i access the resulting HTML of one component to include it in the result page?

Comment: I don't know how it is in Scala. In Java each controller method returns entity of type Result. You can then call .toString() at each Result entity, concatenate them and put the resulting string into the ok(resultingString) method, which outputs the new Result.

Comment: This requirement: "Each of this component should be represented by a separate controller in the new Play application." Why is that? In Play, a controller (or rather, action) is something that takes a request header, asynchronously consumes a request body, and then produces a result which contains a response header and asynchronously produces response body. Out of all that, it sounds like all you want is to invoke a function that synchronously produces a String that you can include in a response. It sounds like you don't want to invoke an action at all.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to invoke an action (what you're calling a controller) - an action is far more than just something that produces some content, 99% of what an action does you don't want to do.

Structure your code so that your actions and your templates that compose these actions both delegate to the same thing, eg:

```
// Foo.java
public class Foo {
  public static String getBar() {
    ...
  }
}

// FooController.java
public class FooController extends Controller {
  public static Result bar() {
    return ok(Foo.getBar());
  }
}

// finalPage.scala.html
@()

@Html(Foo.getBar())
```